# (@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline) - Using "ShellScriptAction" equivalent in a Pipeline made with @aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

Here's my problem. I'm currently struggling to run a basic shell script execution action in my pipeline.
The pipeline was created thru the `Pipeline` construct in `@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline`

```
import { Artifact, IAction, Pipeline } from "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline"
const pipeline = new Pipeline(this, "backend-pipeline",{
...
});
```

Now, I'm running a cross deployment pipeline and would like to invoke a lambda right after it's been created. Before, a simple `ShellScriptAction` would've sufficed in the older (`@aws-cdk/pipelines`) package, but for some reason, both packages `pipelines` and `aws-codepipeline` are both maintained at the same time.

What I would like to know is how to run a simple basic command in the new (`aws-codepipeline`) package, ideally as an `Action` in a `Stage`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline` is for AWS Codepipeline. `@aws-cdk/pipelines` is for utilizing AWS Codepipeline to deploy CDK apps. Read more about the package and its justification [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/).

Regarding your question, you have some options here.

First of all, if you're looking for a simple CodeBuild action to run arbitrary commands, you can use [`CodeBuildAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction.html).

There's a separate action specifically for invoking a lambda, too, it's [`LambdaInvokeAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.LambdaInvokeAction.html).

Both are part of `@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions` module.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `codebuild.PipelineProject` in a [codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction.html) to run arbitrary shell commands in your pipeline. The CDK has several build tool constructs<sup>*</sup>, used in different places. [pipelines.CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) specializes in deploying CDK apps, while the lower-level [codepipeline.Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html) has a broader build capabilities:

| Build tool construct | CloudFormation Resource | Can use where? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`pipelines.ShellStep`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.ShellStep.html) | `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` | `pipelines.CodePipeline` |
| [`pipelines.CodeBuildStep`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html) | `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` | `pipelines.CodePipeline` |
| [`codebuild.PipelineProject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.PipelineProject.html) | `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` | `codepipeline.Pipeline` |
| [`codebuild.Project`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.Project.html) | `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` | `codepipeline.Pipeline` or standalone |

In your case, the setup goes `Pipeline > Stage > CodeBuildAction > PipelineProject`.

```js
// add to stage actions
new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'CodeBuild',
  project: new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'PipelineProject', {
    buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
      version: '0.2',
      phases: {
        build: { commands: ['echo "[project foo] $PROJECT_FOO"'] },
      },
    }),
    environmentVariables: {
      PROJECT_FOO: {
        value: 'Foo',
        type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
      },
    },
  }),
  input: sourceOutput,
});
```

* The `ShellScriptAction` you mentioned is another one, now deprecated in v1 and removed from v2.