# How to create a code pipeline stage to deploy React application with source code in github? [CDK 2.0]

Tags: reactjs, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a React repository in GitHub, and I want to build a pipeline so that whenever I push new commit into the repository, the pipeline will build and deploy to production. I'm using CDK 2.0.

**My pipeline code:**

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";

import { Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import {
  CodePipeline,
  CodePipelineSource,
  ShellStep,
  Step,
} from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
import { ManualApprovalStep } from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
import { PipelineStage } from "./pipeline-stage";

export interface CodePipelineStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  // Built in Stack props
  readonly env: cdk.Environment;
  readonly description: string;
}

export class CodePipelineStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: CodePipelineStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Pipeline", {
      pipelineName: "MyPipeline",
      synth: new ShellStep("Synth", {
        input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
          "github-acount-name/my-react-code",
          "main"
        ),
        commands: [
          'npm ci',
          'npm run build',
          'npx cdk synth'
        ],
      }),
    });

  
    const gammaStage = pipeline.addStage(
      new PipelineStage(this, "Gamma", {
        env: props.env,
      })
    );

    gammaStage.addPre(
      new ShellStep("Run Unit Tests", { commands: ["yarn install", "npm test"] })
    );
    gammaStage.addPost(
      new ManualApprovalStep("Manual approval before production")
    );

    const prodStage = pipeline.addStage(
      new PipelineStage(this, "Prod", {
        env: props.env,
      })
    );
    
  }
}
```

**What should I do here to add my react applications to the pipeline stage code?** I can see from [this example](https://github.com/beabetterdevv/ci-cd-aws-pipeline-demo/blob/main/lib/stage.ts) that it added a `LambdaStack` from local asset. However, I want to build the artifact from my GitHub repository.

```js
export class PipelineStage extends cdk.Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `cdk.Stage` is for deploying CDK Stacks, not for generic build tasks.  Does your pipeline need to deploy stacks or just build the React app?  Where does the React code get built to?  S3?

Comment: @fedonev : my pipeline need to build the react and publish to S3. I guess I need to use CodeBuild similar to this? https://dev.to/aws-builders/continuous-integration-and-delivery-ci-cd-using-aws-cdk-pipelines-with-bitbucket-4hc3

Comment: Do you mind posting an updated solution? It seems that the ```codepipeline.Pipeline``` class is the better route due to it's flexibility. I'm trying to build a React App and deploy it to an S3 bucket in another account, but struggling to find the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options.  To start with, the CDK has two pipeline flavours, [codepipeline.Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html) and  [pipelines.CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html).  The docs have [guidance on which to choose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html), but in a nutshell:

1. `pipelines.CodePipeline` is opinionated and optimised for deploying CDK apps
2. `codepipeline.Pipeline` is more flexible for generic build tasks
3. The two largely overlap - you can solve many problems [using either one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71164724/1103511)
4. Under the hood, both deploy `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` and `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` resources

Which should you choose?  It's a matter of preference, but for generic build tasks I find the `codepipeline.Pipeline` API easier to reason about.  Create a Stack with an S3 destination bucket and a Pipeline construct.  A pipeline has one-or-many [stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html#stages) and each stage has one-or-many [actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html#actions) (`aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions`). Here is one way to approach it:

1. A source stage with a [source action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#sources) to pull your code from a remote repo, like `actions.CodeCommitSourceAction`
2. A [build](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#sources) stage with an `actions.CodeBuildAction` to build the code.  You provide it a [buildspec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html) to give install and build commands, set env vars, etc.
3. A [deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#deploy) stage with an `actions.S3DeployAction` to output the built code to your destination bucket